# NuttShellにはアクセスできるがSpresenseへの書き込みができない

Tags: spresense

Mac上でSpresense SDK（コマンドライン）を使用した開発を行っていましたが、本体への書き込みが不可能になってしまいました。

最も遅い115200bpsで書き込んでいますが、flash_writerが起動するのみで、しばらく待っていても何も起きません。しかし、UARTで接続すると、正常にNuttShellからプログラムを起動することができます。ブートローダーの再書き込みを試しましたが、ブートローダーも同じように書き込みができません。

そこで、本体のリセット、ホストの再起動、USBドライバの再インストール、ケーブルの交換、USBポートの変更、拡張ボードの取り外し、Arduino IDEによる書き込み、Windows上のArduino IDEによる書き込みを試しましたが、結果は同じく書き込みができませんでした。

その後もNuttShellへのアクセスは依然として可能です。ですからこれまでの試みでは、書き込みが始まってすらいないようです。

心当たりがあるとすれば、LTE拡張ボードに電源を接続して動かしている最中に、メインボード側のUSB端子をMacに接続し、その状態で拡張ボード側の電源を抜いて再び指し直したことです。しかし、NuttShellを通じてアクセスは可能であるため、原因が全く分からずお手上げです。（うんともすんとも言わないのならまだ納得は行くのですが...）

このようにしてSpresenseに書き込みができなくなってしまった場合、なにかできることはあるのでしょうか？

もしくは、このような症状の場合、書き込み部？の故障と捉えて新たに買い直すしかないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

工場出荷時の状態にリセットしたところ、無事に解決しました。

結局原因は分からず終いとなり、泣く泣く諦めて新しいメインボードを購入してしまったあと、[Spresense recovery tool](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/spresense-recovery-tool)の存在を英語版ドキュメントにて発見した次第です。

[Spresense SDK スタートガイド](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ja.html)や[Spresense SDK 開発ガイド](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html)にはこのツールについての記載がないため、[サポート](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/29520/spresense)にはその存在だけでも記載していただけたら良いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

LTE拡張ボードのモニターキャンペーンの時に借りた基板で同じ症状が時々発生していました。

その時は、書込みが始まらないときにメインボードのリセットボタンを押すと書込みが開始されました。

すでに試されているかもしれませんが、ご参考まで。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。何とか解決はできましたが、そんな事もあるのですね。"flash_writer.py"のオプションに"-a"を指定した場合はリセットを待機するようでしたので、書き込み中のリセットも試しましたが効果はありませんでした。